# How do I show the number of lines added(and deleted) in git?

Tags: git

I have to display the number of lines added(and deleted) to a certain file by all commits.

Comment: slightly off topic isn't it.

Comment: I think this question is fine. It's no more off-topic than a question about Firefox, Gedit, or unrar, isn't it? (Programmers, by the way, is the wrong site - via their FAQ: "not about [...] programming tools (ask on Stack Overflow instead)")

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo: i think you're right, i've removed my comment.

Comment: I closed on a whim :(... foey. I think this should be reopened.

Answer (score 8):

Use `git log --numstat --oneline <Filename>`. This will give you a list of commits for file `<Filename>`, with two lines for each commit, using this syntax:

```
[sha hash] [commit title line]
[lines added] [lines removed] [path to file in repository]
```